# Bad hierarchy given to \appendix by hyperref

Tags: hyperref, appendices, bookmarks

Here is my problem: in this document, the appendix appears as a chapter inside "part two", but I would like it to appear after this part, as it is an appendix!

Everything is alright in the table of contents. I'm speaking about the bookmarks generated by `hyperref` and used by the PDF viewer (evince for me) to navigate. Those bookmarks don't appear in the PDF file, but in a navigating panel in the viewer. In those links at the left of the screen, "list" appears to be part of the "two", and I would like it to appear after "two".

I hope I'm clear.

[Minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
intro
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{one}
text
\chapter{one-one}
text
\part{two}
text
\chapter{two-one}
text

\appendix
\chapter{list}
list
\backmatter
biblio etc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Differently from forums, we don't use to add “solved” to the title of the question.

Comment: @Malo: If it is solved, please accept one of the two provided solutions then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant command is from `bookmark` package, called `\bookmarksetup` -- since the appendix chapters should be on the same level as the parts, it's necessary to restart the next bookmark level again, using `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}`

The `bookmark` package extends the `hyperref` bookmarking facilities and it does the whole bookmarking in one run, not in at least two runs as usual for most LaTeX compilation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
intro
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{one}
text
\chapter{one-one}
text
\part{two}
text
\chapter{two-one}
text

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\appendix
\chapter{list}
list
\backmatter
biblio etc.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`hyperref` has a companion, `bookmark`, which disables `hyperref`'s bookmarks and gives you some additional power.  Include it and also include:

```
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
```

just before your appendix.  That will fix the issue.

Comment: You were quicker, but I provided the screenshot ;-) (+1)

Comment: It is a fine screenshot, too.  :-)

Comment: Thank you, it worked well, end with this package I will maybe save some time, because the bookmarks now need only need one run instead of two !

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @user31729's answer, I prefer using

```
 \bookmarksetupnext{level=part}
```

before the appendices, so each of the "chapters" in the appendix gets to the next level in the bookmark. After that, just add

```
 \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
```

before the bibliography.