# Putting appendix outside the last part

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, appendices, parts

I have the following LaTeX structure:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\part{Fruits}
\chapter{The Apple}
\chapter{The Peach}
\chapter{The Banana}

\part{Animals}
\chapter{The Dog}
\chapter{The Cat}
\chapter{The Horse}

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}

\chapter{Summary}
\chapter{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

The problem with this is the structure of the bookmark in the final pdf: all the appendices are found within part II.

[image: Bookmark structure]

Is it somehow possible to put the `Appendices` to the outermost level, i.e. parallel with `I Fruits`, `II Animals`, and not inside `II Animals`?

I want to keep the numbering of the table of contents as it is now, i.e. no numbers for chapters within appendix:

[image: Table of Contents]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have a numbering of appendix chapters and for your request, `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixname}` should do

Comment: related: [Bad hierarchy given to \appendix by hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246235/579),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}` instead of `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}`.

Alternatively use the `appendix` package.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\part{Fruits}
\chapter{The Apple}
\chapter{The Peach}
\chapter{The Banana}

\part{Animals}
\chapter{The Dog}
\chapter{The Cat}
\chapter{The Horse}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}
\chapter{Summary}
\chapter{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is logical, and this is what I want to reach. However, unfortunately it does not work at me. The Appendices went within `The Horse`, i.e. on the innermost level. I'm using `pdflatex`, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9).

Comment: @CsabaFaragó: `does not work` is not really helpful. I have the same `pdflatex` version and it apparently does work for me. Do you have done two compilations? Do you have some other  setup?

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough.
First I deleted all intermediary files, only the tex source remains. Then I executed `pdflatex` three times (I've tried it once and two times as well, with the same result).
I tried it also with a deeper structure, and the appendices are put below the last subsection. I.e. it is not always on the third level, but on the innermost level.
The `pdflatex` version see above. My operating system is 64 bit English Windows 7. I open the result pdf using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, version 2015.009.20079, which speaks Hungarian.

Comment: @CsabaFaragó: Well, there's nothing I can do with this. I changed to code a little bit and the `.pdf` shows the `Appendices` bookmark at the right place, both with Acrobat Reader on Linux and Okular

Comment: Thanks for your help; it seems to be another problem. According to your screenshot your solution is indeed the solution for my original problem, therefore I accepted it. Thank you for your help! I try to solve the other problem on another thread.

Comment: @CsabaFaragó: Alright, perhaps I can help again.

Comment: I found the problem! I changed chapter to part only, but omitted the `\phantomsection`. I was careless, your solution is perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: @CsabaFaragó: `\phantomsection` is crucial here!